# where condicao incrementando

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho uma table chamada usuários e quero pega alguns usuários conforme o id então estou fazendo assim:

```
select * from usuarios where id=2;
```

Só que eu gostaria de pegar vários usuários com ids diferentes, por exemplo pegar os usuários que tiver o id 2,8,10,11,20 de uma vez. Como eu poderia fazer isso em SQL? Se eu colocar o `>` **`where id=2 and id=3`**, não daria certo porque ele faz uma comparação. Então alguém saberia me dizer como fazer?

Comment: `select * from usuarios where id=2 OR id=3 OR id=4...`

Comment: da pra utilizar com `in` ex: `select * from usuarios where id in (2, 8, 10)` ou caso preferir, pode utilizar o comando `or` porém, deve envolver todas as condições entre parenteses. ex: `select * from usuarios where (id=2 or id=3 or id=4)`. pois desta maneira ainda podem ser colocadas mais condicoes "fora" dos parenteses. Ex: `select * from usuarios where (id=2 or id=3) and usuarios.nome is not null`.

Answer (score 5):

Use o comando `in`, ele vai verificar se há ocorrências nos campos, e retornar o registro onde houve ocorrências, a finalidade dele é substituir varias clausulas, onde é usado o comando `or`.

Exemplo:

```
select * from usuarios where id in(2,8,10,11,20);
```

Veja mais a respeito dele: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Comment: Massa Dener !! Sabe se existe semelhante ao in no sql server ?

Comment: @JohnDiego Usa da mesma forma, veja a [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx).

Comment: Massa demais !! Brigadão